# Hamiltonian written using Pauli matrices for a two-level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, hamiltonian-formalism, notation

I have the following homework question:

Two electrons are tightly bound to different neighboring sites in a certain solid. They are, therefore, distinguishable particles which can be described in terms of their respective Pauli spin matrices $\sigma^1$ and $\sigma^2$. The Hamiltonian of these electrons takes the form:
$$H=-J(\sigma_x^1 \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^1 \sigma_y^2 )$$
where J is a constant.

How many energy levels does the system have?

Now the solution given to the homework starts by rewriting the Hamiltonian as follows:

$$H=-J/2 ( ( \sigma^1 + \sigma^2 )^2 - (\sigma^1)^2 - (\sigma^2)^2 - (\sigma_z^1 + \sigma_z^2 )^2 - (\sigma_z^1)^2 - (\sigma_z^2)^2 )$$

The solution seems to assume the logic leading from the way the Hamiltonian is formulated initially to this second expression is obvious. I can't honestly see how they got from the way the Hamiltonian was formulated initially to that second expression, perhaps because I'm not clear on what it means to rewrite the Hamiltonian in terms of Pauli matrices as they have done. What am I missing here? How did they convert the first expression into the second one?

Comment: well without even doing any math its obviously 4. reason is, pauli matrices are 2 by 2 and you have tensor product between them thus hamiltonian is 4 by 4 matrix thus you have 4 energy levels. some of them may be degenerate though to be sure, just find eigenvalues of $\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_y$ where $\otimes$ is kronecker product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I could be wrong but...) this seems like just clever rewriting with somewhat obscure notation.  For instance
$$
(\sigma^1+\sigma^2)^2=(\sigma^1)^2+(\sigma^2)^2+2\sigma^1\sigma^2
$$
while
\begin{align}
(\sigma^1)^2&=(\sigma^1_x)^2+(\sigma^1_y)^2+(\sigma^1_z)^2\, ,\tag{1}\\
\sigma^1\sigma^2&=\sigma_x^1\sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^1\sigma_y^2+\sigma_z^1\sigma_z^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
You can see that (2) contains bits of your $H$ so if you add and subtract smartly terms in this way you should land on your feet.

There is an implicit “vector” notation here in that $\sigma^1$ is the “vector” $\vec\sigma^1=(\sigma_x^1,\sigma_y^1,\sigma_z^1)$ so that
$(\sigma^1)^2$ is $\vec\sigma^1\cdot\vec \sigma^1$ as per (1) while something like $\sigma^1\sigma^2$ is $\vec\sigma^1\cdot\vec\sigma^2$ as per (2)